# euler project 23 - can't find the mistake in my code [Java]

Tags: java

After a week that I spent stuck on this problem I can't find where is my mistake.
the problem is:

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>   A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>   As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>   Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

so my code is:

```
package eulerProject;
import java.util.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class e23 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 28123; i++) {

        if (!check(i))
            list.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(list.get(i)));

    System.out.println(sum);

}

public static boolean check(long z) {

    long y = 0;

    for (long i = 1; i <= z / 2; i++) {
        if (abundant(i)) {
            y = z - i;

            if (abundant(y)) {
                return true;
            }

            y = 0;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static long sum(long x) {
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < (Math.sqrt(x)); i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            if (x / i == i) {
                sum += i;
            } else {
                sum = sum + i + (x / i);
            }
        }
    }

    sum = sum - x;
    return sum;
}

public static boolean abundant(long x) {
    if (sum(x) > x)
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

I'll just explain the methods:

"sum" - sums all the proper divisors of a number. 
(like number = 12 , so it sum: 1+2+3+4+6.)

"abundant" - just checks if the number is abundant or not by compairing the sum of his divisors and the number itself.

"check" - generating two numbers which their sum is the number we checking - and checking if the both numbers are abundant. if they are so returns true.

and the main just generating numbers until the max limit, adding to list and then I sum the list.

my answer is: 4190404.
the correct answer is: 4179871.

where is the mistake?

Comment: Rather than summing your list of numbers, save them to a file and compare them with this: http://oeis.org/A048242 . Find the first number in which there is a discrepancy between your list and that list. That should be enough to focus your debugging efforts.

Comment: By the way, your code is extremely inefficient. For example, you are calculating `sum(100)` about 28,000 times. Why not calculate it just once? Create a list of all abundant numbers <= 28123, calling `sum()` just once per number, and then use that list to check if a number is the sum of two abundant numbers.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you!!! 
after doing this I found that this 3 numbers was extra on my list:
1141,1771,7621.
than it made me see that in this row:
 for (int i = 1; i < (Math.sqrt(x)); i++)

I needed to do <= instead of <

can't belive that because of "=" my whole program did'nt worked :(((

Comment: Congratulations on a successful debugging :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum method doesn't get the correct sum for perfect squares because your loop stops before the square root. For example, if you called sum(16), the loop would run up to i = 3 and stop, so 4 would not contribute to the sum.

Solution:

(I also fixed some inefficiencies.)

```
public static long sum(long x){ 
long sum = 1;
int sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(x);

for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
    if (x % i == 0) {
        sum += i + (x/i);
    }
}
//checks if perfect square and subtracts out extra square root.
if(sqrt * sqrt == x) sum -= sqrt;  

return sum;
}
```